# How do I remove the generated query from my Azure Mobile App backend?

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have a cross platform mobile app built using Xamarin Forms and Visual Studio, it uses an Azure Mobile App table api to get its data.  What I noticed was that the backend seems to run an additional query for incremental sync which checks the `updatedAt` columns timestamp.

Does anyone know where the query is generated (or what file holds it) within the `node.js` backend on Azure or rather, how I can remove it?  It's a condition that we don't need as it's generating ghost data in the apps `listview` which is making everything appear as incorrect.

To clarify the `node.js` backend mobile app was automatically generated on Azure using `Easy Tables` within the Mobile App configuration (https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/).  You simply add the name of your table and it will add the `version`, `deleted`, `updatedAt` and `createdAt` columns to the table for you.

It's an odd one but I feel totally out of control with my data, the app I made is ready only so the end user never deletes or updates anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know where the query is generated (or what file holds it) within the node.js backend on Azure or rather, how I can remove it?

The additional query is added when you invoke the `PullAsync` with a non-null query ID. As the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) states about **Incremental Sync**:

> The first parameter to the pull operation is a query name that is used only on the client. **If you use a non-null query name, the Azure Mobile SDK performs an incremental sync. Each time a pull operation returns a set of results, the latest updatedAt timestamp from that result set is stored in the SDK local system tables. Subsequent pull operations retrieve only records after that timestamp**.

For disable the additional query based on the `updatedAt` column, you could pass null as the **query ID**. In this case, all records are retrieved on every call via `PullAsync` as follows:

```
await todoTable.PullAsync(null, todoTable.CreateQuery().Where(t => t.UserId == "<userid>"));
```

> It's a condition that we don't need as it's generating ghost data in the apps listview which is making everything appear as incorrect.

Per my understanding, Incremental Sync is used to optimize pulling server data into your device. Here are some attentions, you could check with your application:

- Since the Azure Mobile Client SDK adds its own sort on the `updatedAt` field, you cannot use a pull query that has its own `orderBy` clause.
- The query name can be any string you choose, but it must be unique for each logical query in your app. Otherwise, different pull operations could overwrite the same incremental sync timestamp and your queries can return incorrect results.

For more details, you could refer to [Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync).

Additionally, for `PullAsync` with non-null query id, after successfully retrieve the data and update to your local data store, then the client SDK would update/insert the `__config` table with the latest `updatedAt` timestamp from the pulled result along with the `id` equals `deltaToken|{table-name}|{query-id}` for your SQLite db as follows:

[image]